# Wix Bootstrapper MSI-Package logging, how?

Tags: logging, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I have a bootstrapper that installs a *MSI-package.*

How can i achieve that at least the msi-package-installation gets logged(*verbose logging*)? And where can i set the log-file-path? Because I won't be able to log everything i guess?

And no, i **don't** want a **cmd-solution**, i need to implement this **into my setup**

Found LogPathVariable, but don't really know how it works?

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Setup.TargetPath)" LogPathVariable="" />
```

Googled arround many times and havn't found a solution for this problem, any help?

Answer (score 9):

The default case (no LogPathVariable set) will create logs in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp the MSI logs will be verbose, there will also be a log for the bootstrapper.

For a custom destination you can create a Variable and set it

```
<Variable Name="MyLogDestination" Type="string" Value=path to where you want log created />
```

You could use one of the [burn variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html) in conjunction with a partial path. I think

```
<Variable Name="MyLogDestination" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFiles6432Folder]\YourProduct\" />
```

might work though I've not tried it.

You would then put your variable name in the LogPathVariable

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Setup.TargetPath)" LogPathVariable="MyLogDestination" />
```

Comment: But how can i save this log file into the install-directory?

Comment: I updated my answer with information for the custom destination case.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesnt work. My created variable gets overwritten by the default log-location (%TEMP%) every time

Answer (score 3):

That's how I did:

Add Log element under Bundle:

```
 <Log PathVariable="LOGPATH_PROP" Disable="yes" Prefix='[WixBundleOriginalSource]' Extension=".txt" />
```

and then set the LogPathVariable to "LOGPATH_PROP" in MsiPackage element. The key is to set the Disable attribute to yes in Log element.

Answer (score 1):

Both bundle installation and the packages logs will be created into `%TEMP%` (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp).

The naming scheme for the log file is:

*BundleName_yyyyMMddHHmmss.log*

Where the date and time is when the installation started. For each chained MSI package, Burn automatically enables verbose logging. The chained package log file naming scheme is:

*BundleName_yyyyMMddHHmmss_#_PackageId.log*

Where # indicate the order that the package was applied. The same package may show up multiple times with #s if the installation failed and the package was removed during rollback. (for example BundleName_yyyyMMddHHmmss_002_FailedPackage_rollback.log)

In order to get the bundle installer location path you can use `BootstrapperApplication.Engine.StringVariables[WixBundleLog]`, in order to get the package log file you can use `BootstrapperApplication.Engine.StringVariables[WixBundleLog_packageId]`.

if you want to change the default location (`%TEMP%`) you can use the `LogPathVariable` attribute of the MsiPackage element to provide a custom log file name:

See: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html

Also: https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912207-Pass-Properties-to-MsiPackage-from-Bundle-

Answer (score 0):

this will create empty logs folder for you...

```
<Directory Id="LOGSDIR" Name="logs">
    <Component Guid="GUID" Id="ID" KeyPath="no" NeverOverwrite="no" Permanent="no" Location="local" Permanent="no">
        <CreateFolder>
            <util:PermissionEx CreateChild="yes" CreateFile="yes" Delete="yes" DeleteChild="yes" Read="yes" ReadAttributes="yes" ReadExtendedAttributes="yes" ReadPermission="yes" Traverse="yes" GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes" User="Everyone" />
        </CreateFolder>
    </Component>
</Directory>
```