# BURN: Customize Log File Location

Tags: wix, burn

All I am trying, is to set Log file location and expect BURN to create Log File to my given location.
I have tried this by following [Wix Bootstrapper MSI-Package logging, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424363/wix-bootstrapper-msi-package-logging-how) post, but got no success and BURN still created LOG Files at default (%TEMP%) location.

Looking forward for guidelines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See answer from below question

[How to log an installation made from a WiX bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596548/how-to-log-an-installation-made-from-a-wix-bundle)

There is a Wix variable called `WixBundleLog` which holds and sets the log file location for Burn bundles, however this is a Wix variable and can't be overwritten with a custom value within the bundle